# Как генерировать кэш лишь единожды при множестве одновременных запросов?

Tags: apache, кэширование

Можно ли в в веб-сервере на Apache + PHP организовать ожидание создания кэша со стороны Apache, перед обработкой новых запросов?

Предположим, есть страница по адресу `www.site.ru/page1`, кэш для которой еще не сгенерирован, а время генерации кэша этой страницы - 5 секунд.

Далее, одновременно на эту страницу поступает 10 запросов, и, как я полагаю, все они сразу начнут генерировать один и тот же кэш.

Можно ли настроить сервер так, чтобы обрабатываться начал только первый запрос, если кэша нет, а остальные ждали, пока первый запрос отработает и сразу получили бы готовый кэш?

Comment: Первый процесс начиная создавать кеш ставит блокировку на какой либо файл, например на тот в котором будет кеш. Другие процессы так же берут блокировку и будут ждать на ней. когда превый закончит они продолжат работу, обнаружат что кеш есть снимут блок и отдадут инфу ихз кеша

Comment: А чтобы реализовать это в apache, есть готовые решения?

Comment: Если вы возьмете полную блокировку по чтению, то апач конечно то же остановится при попытке прочитать файл. Только я не думаю, что стоит тормозить апачевский процесс на 5 сек.